# How to deduce a separate element from the dictionary value?

Tags: python, list

```
apartments = dict(living_room = ['sofa', 'coffee table', 'bookshelf', 'armchair'],
                  kitchen = ['stove', 'fridge', 'sink', 'shelves'],
                  bedroom = ['closet', 'bureau', 'bed', 'blinds', 'chest of drawers'],
                  bathroom = ['shower', 'bathtub', 'lavatory pan', 'shower cubicle'])

first_customer = ('I see you have a nice {}, you can sell to me that?'.format(*apartments['kitchen']))

print(first_customer)
```

---

I see you have a nice **fridge**, you can sell to me that?

Comment: Meaning? What exactly you want to do?

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: Do you want your `first_customer` variable to be a list of this sentence with every kitchen element?

Comment: first_customer = ('I see you have a nice {}, you can sell to me that?'.format(*apartments['kitchen'][0]))

Comment: Kostas Charitidis Yes.

Comment: @Raady this will print only the first letter of the first element of kitchen. Meaning only an `s`

Comment: Raady
I tried so, it gives the letter index from the first element.
`I see you have a nice s, you can sell to me that?`

Comment: sorry, * should be removed. format(apartments['kitchen'][0]))

Comment: Raady
You best of the best!
Thats what i need.

Answer (score 2):

## UPDATE

So this will do the trick if I got you right:

```
first_customer = ['I see you have a nice {}, you can sell to me that?'.format(x) for x in apartments['kitchen']]
print('\n'.join(first_customer))
```

`first_customer` should be initialized as a list and then take every value in a for loop (or [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) as above) and format it to your string.

So if you want to print the second element of `kitchen` do the following:

```
print(first_customer[1])
```

Comment: Thats very nice.  Thanks. 
But I want a specific element to be displayed. And not listing all.

Comment: @RustamBainazarov explain a bit more

Comment: `first_customer = ('I see you have a nice {}, you can sell to me that?'.format(apartments['kitchen'][1]))`
 Kostas Charitidis Raady explained how to do it :)

Comment: @RustamBainazarov Oh well see the updated solution.